# Прогрессивная загрузка ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть php-скрипт, который обращается к API и получает от него данные на протяжении 5-10 секунд. Можно ли как-то загружать эти данные по мере получения на клиенте через ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax работает по системе запрос-ответ, поэтому получать данные частично в процессе работы php не получится.

Для аналогичного случая долгих запросов делал так.

1. Асинхронный ajax к "тяжелому" скрипту php.
2. Этот скрипт пишет результат в файл на сервере.
3. Тем временем по таймеру каждые 2 секунды запускаются ajax для считывания этого файла и обновления страницы.